# Generalize power spectrum density to higher order spectral moment

Tags: fourier-transform, power, turbulence

If the power spectrum density for a given time series is given by :

$PSD(f) = \frac{2 \Delta}{N} \sum_{j=1}^{N} \delta B^{2}(t_{j}, f)$,

where, where $δB(t_{j} , f)$ is the magnitude of the trace fluctuations at time $t_{j}$ and frequency $f$, $∆$ is the sampling time between consecutive measurements, and N is the sample size at each frequency.

Then if we want to generalize to a higher order Spectral moment is the expression for the q_{th} moment (for convenience denoted as $M^{q}$):

$M^{q}(f) = \frac{2 \Delta}{N} \sum_{j=1}^{N} \delta B^{q}(t_{j}, f)$,

correct?

Or do I need to change something in the coefficient $\frac{2 \Delta}{N}$ also?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.  Generally moments in regards to measurements of the magnetic field are with respect to finite differences between time-lagged measurements.  Is the PSD a moment of something?  I don't think it is.  Regardless, the constant factors out front are for purposes of units and normalization to match that of a Fourier transform.

Comment: @honeste_vivere I was reading this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.5938.pdf. I was wondering if since one could recover the scaling exponent of the second order structure function from the PSD, wether or not we could generalize it to higher order moments

Comment: Yeah, see the structure functions are dependent upon the finite difference of the magnetic field at some variable time-lag.  This is the $\tau$ variable in their equation 2.  It looks similar to the PSD but is a different measure of a different quantity.

Comment: So we would not expect it to scale like q/3 or q/4 like the regular scaling exponents?